# Deny Certain Domain Users TO login as the administrator

Tags: lan

We have a little problem.  The company I'm working for now has one main admin account.  This is a problem as some contractors knows the password and then login using the admin account and not there own.

The problem is that if we do change the password, the account will be logged out as there is about 200 contractors.

I need to restrict those 200 contractors from sing the admin account.  But everyone not part of the list of 200 should still be able to use the admin account for remote desktoping.

Any help would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you NEVER allow ANYONE who is not the admin to use the admin account.What you are going to need to do is create elevated privileged accounts for your contractors that can do what they'll need to do, then tell them to log into those accounts and once every contractor has logged out/in, change the admin password, be polite but firm, you can add permissions to any contractor that needs it but none of them get the admin account anymore. It's just too dangerous for everyone. they are not idiots, they'll understand.

edit: as for everyone else who needs remote access make accounts for them too, hell if you trust them, you could make sub-admin accounts, but just don't let everyone use the admin account. It WILL end up biting you in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about local networking, I've only had experience with ssh networking, but have you thought of using private keys? Again I know this works for my purposes, not certain for local.

[Here's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/) a good guide to a linux setup. Don't know about other OS's.

There should also be some sort of disciplinary action to stop people logging into wrong accoutns, especially admin ones.